# Teclado en pantalla

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vb.net, visual

Tengo una pantalla táctil con la que registro diferentes valores en diferentes pantallas. Ahora mismo los datos los introduzco a través de un botón que llama a "osk.es". Como puedo hacer que al hacer click en un textbox se abra directamente un teclado en pantalla y al salir de ese textbox se cierre?

Sino otra forma que también me vendría bien seria que el teclado al yo darle al boton aparezca en una parte determinada de la pantalla con una medida indicada tambien.

Utilizo VS 2010, se que es antiguo ya...

Gracias

Comment: Entiendo que estas usando [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-8.0) para lanzarlo. Para abrirlo al pulsar en el textbox puedes simplemente suscribirte al evento GotFocus o Clicked y lanzarlo ahi. En cuanto a cerrarlo, puedes llamar a Kill del proceso en el evento LostFocus

Comment: Creo que tienes que configurar Windows, algo como modo tablet, con esto al hacer focus en un input se abre automáticamente el teclado en pantalla

Comment: Gracias, en modo tableta lo he probado y no funcionaba. He probado con el gotfocus y esta funcionandome, ahora me faltaria crear de alguna forma un array que me coja todos los textbox de todos los formularios y que a traves del gotfocus abra el teclado, alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Y hay alguna forma de elegir tamaño y posicion donde aparece el teclado?

Comment: Para que se lance en todos los textbox, simplemente enlaza el evento gotfocus de todos al mismo manejador de eventos. En cuanto al tamaño, diría que no hay forma de modificarlo por linea de comandos, tal vez con el registro en todo caso.